# The Social Security Special Earnings Limit Rule---How Long is the Cap on Hours Worked in One's Own Business Truly in Effect?

Tags: united-states, retirement, self-employment, social-security, early-retirement

I am under the impression that retirees who are collecting Social Security benefits and start a business are capped in the number of hours they can work between 15 and 45 hours per month if they have not reached full retirement age.

For example, see https://www.ssa.gov/benefits/retirement/planner/rule.html

However, and in particular, we find the following in the given link:

[image]

[image]

Notice the last sentence: ``Beginning in 2023, the deductions are based solely on John's annual earnings limit.''

This sounds as if, John, who is age 62 (not full retirement age) will not be subject to the hours cap of 15-45 hours per month in his business beginning in 2023.

Is this correct? Again, I am under the impression that the limitation on hours worked in one's own business is in effect (at least) until full retirement age which can be up to 67 for some people. Also, I have not been able to find a source which specifically indicates that the hours restriction IS dropped at full retirement age as is the limit on earnings.

QUESTION: What specifically is the cap on hours worked in one's own business when collecting Social Security benefits; and---(1) does it go away at full retirement age (2) does it go away the year after one starts collecting Social Security benefits (as is suggested in the EXAMPLE of "John" provided by the SSA.) (3) Or, does the cap on hours worked in self-employment never go away?